# vue-toasted Clear toasts without animations

Tags: vue.js, vue-toasted

I am trying to clear all toasts immediately in vue-toasted, but there is a pretty long sliding animations. How do i disable them or is there any other method to clear them all without sliding? i use `this.$toasted.clear()`